Animator Controller preventing change to Sprite Renderer from code, despite no animation clip changing the sprite
I have an "Enemy" Animator Controller:

The enemy dead clip disables the Sprite Renderer after 4 frames:

The EnemyDamaged clip just moves position and rotation for a few frames:

For my green blob, I've set up an override controller that overrides the above clips with a series of sprites:


So, a Blue or Red blob uses the standard "Enemy" animator controller that only turns on/off the SpriteRenderer, but does not change the sprite. The Green slime uses the Green Slime's "Override" animator controller with the override clips that do change the sprites.
The following code runs on my Enemy.cs script to spawn a new monster. When a Green slime dies (the only enemy with an override animator controller), the next spawned enemy always has the base green sprite, but if a red or blue slime dies the next enemy's sprite is updated correctly.
public void Initialize(Monster monster)
{
    animator.ResetTrigger("Dead");
    animator.ResetTrigger("Damaged");
    health = monster.health;
    maxHealth = monster.health;
    attack = monster.attack;
    defense = monster.defense;
    this.monster = monster;
    enemyNameText.text = monster.name;
    spriteRenderer.sprite = monster.sprite;
    currentHealthTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal, maxHealthTransform.rect.width * (float)health / maxHealth);
    animator.runtimeAnimatorController = monster.animatorController ? monster.animatorController : defaultAnimatorController;
    animator.SetTrigger("Spawned");
}

If I change the code to the following to only ever use the defaultAnimatorController for all enemy types, the issue disappears, but I can no longer override my animations:
public void Initialize(Monster monster)
{
    animator.ResetTrigger("Dead");
    animator.ResetTrigger("Damaged");
    health = monster.health;
    maxHealth = monster.health;
    attack = monster.attack;
    defense = monster.defense;
    this.monster = monster;
    enemyNameText.text = monster.name;
    spriteRenderer.sprite = monster.sprite;
    currentHealthTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal, maxHealthTransform.rect.width * (float)health / maxHealth);
    animator.runtimeAnimatorController = defaultAnimatorController;
    animator.SetTrigger("Spawned");
}

Here's a GIF of the bug happening. Notice how after the green slime dies, the sprite stays green despite it spawning a red slime and having the original "Enemy" animator controller that does not affect the SpriteRenderer.

If you're interested in tinkering with the code yourself, here's a link to a github repo of that produces this bug.

My current proposed solution is to destroy the instance of enemy, and create a new one from the spawner. This will work to resolve my issue, but I'd like to better understand why setting the SpriteRenderer.sprite is ignored when there's an override controller.

As soon as any animation clip holds a key frame to a property it is bound to the animator and can not be modified by script - or better is overruled by the animator as it run last in a frame

This gave me the right direction to look. The active controller is showing as "Enemy" at the end of the frame, which doesn't bind to the .sprite property.
Interestingly, moving the spriteRenderer.sprite line to after the animator assignment seems to resolve this. It looks like the animatorController is blocking changes to affected properties, rather than binding/overruling them.
Where can I read more on the property blocking/binding functionality of the animator controller? @derHugo

idk to be honest ^^ that's just from the experiences I made with animations in Unity .. the system itself is unfortunately quite closed book as soon as the use case goes beyond the "normal"

but yeah first changing the controller and only then the properties makes a lot sense from that perspective - as said on the inside no clue how the aniamtor does it exactly but seems that as long as the controller still claims ownership of a property it is already marked to be set for this frame (which is weird - probably almost a bug - but seems to be what it is)

@derHugo "Properties binded by an animator controller cannot be changed. "  Properties bound by animation clip are updated in the internal animation update. Try updating them in the LateUpdate and you'll see they can be changed, indeed. https://docs.unity3d.com/6000.0/Documentation/Manual/execution-order.html

@PhillipZoghbi yes as mentioned I was a bit sloppy worded on this .. animator is one of the last things to run - sure you can use Lastupdate or WaitForEndOfFrame to hardcore overrule properties.. in a quite artificial way. But here the question was why the order matters whether you first assigned a property or a new animator controller overwrite

Thanks to DerHugo's comment, I was able to identify the issue.
Here are some key things to know:

Animator Controllers bind to all properties that are affected by its animation clips
The Animator Override Controller was binding to the SpriteRenderer's sprite property through one of its animation clips
The default animator controller was not binding to the SpriteRenderer's sprite property
Properties binded by an animator controller cannot be changed. The animator controller does not "override" the property. It blocks changes to the property entirely.

The cause of the problem:
If the Green Slime controller is active while trying to set the SpriteRenderer's .sprite property, that line of code is ignored because changes to the .sprite property are controlled in one of its animation clip overrides.
If the Default controller is active while trying to set the .sprite property, the line of code executes without problem.
The base sprite updates correctly after Red and Blue slimes die because the Default controller is active (not binding the property). The base sprite does not update correct after a Green slime dies because the Green slime's override controller is active (binding and blocking the property).
The solution is 2-fold:

Update the animation controller before setting the sprite.

public void Initialize(Monster monster)
{
    animator.ResetTrigger("Dead");
    animator.ResetTrigger("Damaged");
    health = monster.health;
    maxHealth = monster.health;
    attack = monster.attack;
    defense = monster.defense;
    this.monster = monster;
    enemyNameText.text = monster.name;
    currentHealthTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal, maxHealthTransform.rect.width * (float)health / maxHealth);
    animator.runtimeAnimatorController = defaultAnimatorController;
    spriteRenderer.sprite = monster.sprite; //Moving this line here fixes the problem for the default animator controller
    animator.SetTrigger("Spawned");
}


Create an idle animation clip for the Green slime's override animator controller, and set the SpriteRenderer's base sprite in the first frame. This is because the override animator controller is binding and blocking changes to that property directly, so the animator controller needs to make the change through an animation clip.


It makes sense since you're not updating the sprite when entering an idle state (you have no animation clip in this state!)
You almost had it.
The approach overall isn't the best, but following your structure, there's a simple solution and explanation.
The problem is that you're setting the animator controller after setting the sprite, making the sprite change redundant.
Simply call spriteRenderer.sprite = monster.sprite; after animator.runtimeAnimatorController = monster.animatorController ? monster.animatorController : defaultAnimatorController;
Refined code:
public void Initialize(Monster monster)
{
    animator.ResetTrigger("Dead");
    animator.ResetTrigger("Damaged");
    health = monster.health;
    maxHealth = monster.health;
    attack = monster.attack;
    defense = monster.defense;
    this.monster = monster;
    enemyNameText.text = monster.name;
currentHealthTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal, maxHealthTransform.rect.width * (float)health / maxHealth);
    animator.runtimeAnimatorController = monster.animatorController ? monster.animatorController : defaultAnimatorController;
    spriteRenderer.sprite = monster.sprite; // moved after setting animator
    animator.SetTrigger("Spawned");
}


Unfortunately, this is not the correct solution and would not resolve it. You can test your code changes if you like, there's a github link. DerHugo was right, the active animator blocks any changes to binded properties, but doesn't throw an error. I had to update to an animator that does not bind to the sprite property before updating the sprite.

check the new solution, i edited my answer. i was able to load your project and solve it

That's what I said is how to solve it. Updating the animator before updating the sprite. unfortunately, your explanation is incorrect. There is an animation clip in the idle state, but it doesn't override the sprite. Also, setting the animator controller after the sprite does not make setting the sprite redundant because the default animator is not changing the sprite. I'll go ahead and provide the answer that DerHugo guided me towards.

no, there is not. if we're talking about the same project that you shared, there are 4 animation clips: Damaged, Dead, EnemyDamaged, EnemyDead. There is not clip in the Idle state, it's an empty state and what I said makes total sense. You can't expect to change the sprite because you're not changing the sprite in the animator. At least not in the idle state

I'm not expecting the animator to change the sprite. The idle state has a null animation clip, so I should be able to alter the sprite property. The problem is the overall animator controller blocking the change of all properties, despite the idle state not binding to the property. Animators are supposed to override component values, not block them entirely. This appears to be a bug with animator controllers blocking changes to binded properties.

If you're tenacious about your approach, you will have to make additional animation clips for idle state, like it's intended, and use AnimatorOverrideController.ApplyOverrides more information here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorOverrideController.html

You have a tendency to just say "Your approach is wrong" and then not following up with a correct approach. You have spent more time trying to tear down my credentials. It's really silly, especially considering I've been active in the Unity StackOverflow community for over 5 years.
Additionally, the ApplyOverrides reference you linked is referencing how to create a new AnimatorOverrideController via code. That is not applicable to this use-case. The AnimatorOverride already exists as an asset.

Take a look at DerHugo's comment on the main post, or the answer I've marked for a full explanation of the cause of the issue and the resolution.
